# How to annotate the difference between blended vowels and non-blended vowels

Tags: ipa, vowels

Similar to [this question about consonants](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/29166/how-to-annotate-popping-vs-non-popping-sounds-of-sequential-consonants), I'm wondering how you annotate with IPA (or any other system if IPA doesn't support it) the difference between *blending* vowels together (morphing between multiple vowels) and *discretely shifting* between them.

For example, the word "wow" is really like 3 different vowel sounds from what it seems. So I would maybe do /ʊɛʊ/. But this is **blending** the sounds together.

A different way to do it to demonstrate non-blending is to use glottal stops, /ʊʔɛʔʊ/, or "ʊ'ɛ'ʊ". But that is essentially putting a pause between the sounds which is the extreme.

In the middle, in between blending and putting pauses between the sounds, is just shifting from one to the next without blending. A way to replicate this is to pronounce each long, and transition to the next quickly, so "ʊʊʊʊʊʊʊɛɛɛɛɛɛɛɛɛʊʊʊʊʊʊʊʊ". If you do this quickly but not so quickly as to *morph* or *blend* them together, then it's not a glottal stop and not a blend, so it's a ________ I don't know, a **discrete shift**.

Wondering how to annotate this in IPA. It seems then there are 3 types:

- blending
- discretely shifting
- glottal stops

Wondering how to write all 3. If there are more ways to do it than these 3 types, that would be good to know too!

Comment: Anyone volunteering to transcribe [Owen Wilson Says WOW](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KlLMlJ2tDkg)? :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways that the IPA can annotate such differences.  The first is a tiebar: u͡a (unicode 0361) or u͜a (unicode 035C).  Use of a tiebar is usually taken to indicate "these two vowels are part of a single phoneme" (i.e., they form a diphthong), which technically indicates something about their behavior in the phonological patterns of the language, but usually also means they are pronounced more "blended" (to use your term).

A way to indicate that the vowels are more "discrete" is to explicitly mark them as members of separate syllables, using a period (as in /a.u/, or if the second syllable is [prominent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_(linguistics)), /aˈu/ or /aˌu/).

A third way one might (ab)use the IPA to denote a "blended" vs "discrete" vowel sequence would be to mark one of the vowels as an onglide or offglide, using /j/ (in place of /i/), /w/ (in place of /u/) or /ɰ/ (in place of /ɯ/).  Personally I don't think that's a very good approach, for a couple of related reasons:

1. Technically those symbols represent consonants, not vowels, and so /aj/ ought to be considered a V-C sequence, which makes it no longer just a vowel.
2. In speech the glide-vowel or vowel-glide transition is often quite "blended" and may be indistinguishable from a diphthong solely on auditory or acoustic grounds. In other words, the question of whether English "pie" is transcribed as /pa͜i/ (two phonemes, CV) or /paj/ (three phonemes, CVC) depends more on larger-scale patterns of how the [aɪ] sound(s) behave in different contexts, rather than on how blended or discrete the sounds are (e.g., if English "pie" follows a phonological rule that is followed by other words that are unambiguously CVC and not by words that are unambiguously CV, you might argue on that basis that /paj/ is correct).

As a final aside: when vowels are adjacent in speech with continuous voicing, they will never be fully "discrete". There will always be a period of transition in the vowel quality, because when the jaw/tongue/lips move to make the second vowel gesture, the size and shape of the air mass in the oral cavity changes too, and that change is never instantaneous.